# crontab python subprocess and service restart

Tags: python, linux, cron

I have a small python code that restarts nginx on it's not existing.
When I run `sudo python monitor_server.py` all is fine.
When I tried to cron it with root cron (`sudo crontab -e`) with the line:
`* * * * * python /root/monitor_server.py > /var/log/my_monitor/cron_log.log 2>&1`
I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/monitor_server.py", line 19, in <module>
    restart_service('mongod')
  File "/root/monitor_server.py", line 10, in restart_service
    subprocess.call(command, shell=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 478, in call
    p = Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The code:

```
def restart_service(name):
    command = ['service', name, 'restart'];
    #shell=FALSE for sudo to work.
    subprocess.call(command, shell=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen("<healthcheck URL>")
    except (urllib2.HTTPError, urllib2.URLError) as e:
        logging.log(logging.ERROR, 'restarting server')
        restart_service('nginx')
```

Comment: try calling `service` with absolute path, like `usr/sbin/service`.

Comment: Use [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) instead of cron.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky - didn't help, same result

Comment: @ChristianBerendt - tried making moni work for hours. It didn't restart my nginx no matter what I tried

Comment: @Boaz Sorry for a typo, there should be leading slash, so you shall try `/usr/sbin/service` (or what ever you get returned by `which service`). Anyway, I do not guarantee, it would work, just an idea.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky - It worked thanks! It's funny how you neglect double checking when getting an answer on stackoverflow... Write it as an answer to get accetped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling the command using absolute path, as you call it without shell and under another user account, some commands are not available without specifying absolute path.

First find, where is the command located:

```
$ which service
/usr/sbin/service
```

Then change your code to:

```
def restart_service(name):
    command = ['/usr/sbin/service', name, 'restart'];
    #shell=FALSE for sudo to work.
    subprocess.call(command, shell=False)
```