# check tor connection is established before running scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, tor

I'd like to check tor before I start crawling using python scrapy. I am using [polipo/tor/scrapy](http://pkmishra.github.io/blog/2013/03/18/how-to-run-scrapy-with-TOR-and-multiple-browser-agents-part-1-mac/) on linux.

with this settup scrapy correctly using tor on its crawls. The way I check if the scrapy using tor correctly is to crawl [this page](https://check.torproject.org/) in myspider.

```
class mySpider(scrapy.Spider): 
    def start_requests(self):
         yield Request('https://check.torproject.org/', self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
         logging.info("Check tor page:" + str(response.css('.content h1::text')))
```

However I think there might be a better/clean way of doing it. I know I can [check tor service status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24160063/3990158) or [check ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481419/how-can-i-get-the-public-ip-using-python2-7) but I want to actually check whether tor connection is correctly established.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat definitive way to do this is to connect to Tor's control port and issue `GETINFO status/circuit-established`.

If Tor has an active circuit built, it will return:

```
250-status/circuit-established=1
250 OK
```

If Tor hasn't been used for a while, this could be 0.  You can also call `GETINFO dormant` which would yield `250-dormant=1`.  Most likely when you then try to use Tor, it will build a circuit and dormant will become 0 and circuit-established will be 1 barring any major network issues.

In either case, dormant=0 or circuit-established=1 should be enough to tell you can use Tor.

It's a simple protocol so you can just open a socket to the control port, authenticate, and issue commands, or use [Controller](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html#stem.control.Controller) from Stem.

See the [control spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/control-spec.txt) for more info.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I just noticed twisted is using txtorcon and not stem so I guess scrapy is using txtorcon so I guess I should learn how to getinfo in txtorcon instead

Comment: Looks like it does [torcontrolprotocol.py](https://github.com/meejah/txtorcon/blob/master/txtorcon/torcontrolprotocol.py#L384).  Might as well use that, but it's a very simple command based protocol with nothing special for simple commands like that.  It does however get more complicated with parsing of certain results and knowing how to identify the end of a message.

Comment: If I understand correctly `dormant` and `circuit-established` will return 1 and 0 respectively if Tor hasn't been used for a while. (1) Do these commands wake up Tor? (2) If not what would be the best way to wake it up?

Comment: Just asking the controller for that info doesn't wake up Tor.  You can wake it with a `SIGNAL NEWNYM`, by trying to resolve an address `RESOLVE somehost.net`, or by opening a SOCKS connection and issuing a request (there will be some small lag up front to build circuits and establish the connections before sending the request).  I can't say with absolute certainty but I don't think Tor can be dormant if you have established circuits since dormant is described as `zero if Tor is currently active and building circuits, and nonzero if Tor has gone idle due to lack of use or some similar reason`.